# MS Graph: Get all users by manager id

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to gather all users with a given manager's id.
It seems that MS graph has a bug here.

My query:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=manager/id eq '0f3b8a2f-8bec-4694-8021-dbfc55eed287'
```

I expect this query to return all the users that belong to the manager with the given id.
However, this query returns **the manager** and not the users. But I clearly filter the **id of the manager related property** and not the user's id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an API specifically for this, [List directReports](https://learn.microsoft.com/graph/api/user-list-directreports).

You can get the users assigned to the manager with id `0f3b8a2f-8bec-4694-8021-dbfc55eed287` like:

```
GET /users/0f3b8a2f-8bec-4694-8021-dbfc55eed287/directReports
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be

```
GET /users/0f3b8a2f-8bec-4694-8021-dbfa55eed297?$expand=directReports
```